# systemd+ - cannot stop mongo service

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, systemd

I noticed mongo was listening on port 27017

I tried to stop it with:

> $ sudo systemctl stop mongod Failed to stop mongod.service: Unit

> mongod.service not loaded.

and then I did:

> sudo service mongod stop Failed to stop mongod.service: Unit

> mongod.service not loaded.

then I had to do:

```
ps aux | grep mongo
```

and I saw

```
systemd+    2082  0.0  0.7 2581952 127376 ?      Ssl  Feb04   3:02 mongod --bind_ip_all
```

so what is systemd+ and how do I manage it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copied and Pasted [StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73031797/why-use-use-elf-the-result-return-username-with-systemd)

`ps` (sadly) trims the username to 8 (if I'm counting right) characters and adds a + after the user name initial part. The username could be `systemd-mysql` or `systemd-something` that you can find in passwd.

From manual:

> If the length of the username is greater than the length of the display column, the username will be truncated. See the -o and -O formatting options to customize length

Comment: ohh damn, that makes some sense

Comment: Yup I had to Google that one.  I've never seen `systemd+` either